# how to do the each function for all to checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to check if the checkbox is checked or not..

```
    $('#nextpage').click(function() {
       var result = $('#Details input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked');
        if (result == true) {
            $("#tabs").tabs('enable', 3).tabs('select', 3);
        }
        else {
            $().ShowDialog('please select atleast one');
        }
    });
```

Using this I can check only for one checkbox. If I need to check for multiple checkboxes in the Details page how do I need to loop throw?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understood from the discussion and code is that you want to switch tab only if one or more checkboxes are checked otherwise open a dialog box.

```
$('#nextpage').click(function() {
    var collection  = $('#Details input:checked');
   if(collection.length > 0 ) {
            //either loop on collection array or switch tab
            $("#tabs").tabs('enable', 3).tabs('select', 3);
   } else {
            $().ShowDialog('please select atleast one');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly how you're using this in relation to the rest of your code, but this uses the each to check every checkbox:

```
$('#nextpage').click(function() {
    $('#Details input[type=checkbox]').each( function() {
        if( $(this).attr('checked') ) {
            $("#tabs").tabs('enable', 3).tabs('select', 3);
        } else {
            $().ShowDialog('please select atleast one');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If I use this I am not getting the pop up message when  i dint selected anything?
thanks

Comment: I don't know the ShowDialog function you're using, but you can try an alert. The each means it will alert it for EACH checkbox that is not selected.

If you just want to check them all, you can try to add on a :checked to the end of the selector and count how many rows you get (if 0, then nothing is checked)